# Why can't I run TexMaker?

Tags: qt, archlinux, tex, texmaker

### Background

Currently workingh on an `Arch Linux` and I want to modify and edit `tex` documents. I though `texmaker` would be the best available tool for this.

### Problem

It seems to have installed perfectly, but I get the error below whenever I try to run `texmaker` from the terminal. If I double click to the shortcut, I don't even get an error.

```
texmaker: /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.8' not found
(required by /usr/lib/libQt5Sensors.so.5) 
texmaker:/usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.8' not found 
(required by /usr/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5) 
texmaker: /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.8' not found 
(required by /usr/lib/libQt5WebChannel.so.5)
```

Is this related to [ROS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System) that I have installed on my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a simple `yaourt -Syu` and now it works!